# Absolute positioning, percentage heights and flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I want a flexbox container that has a maximum height (say 50% of its container). Pretty simple right?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.list {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.fixed {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="fixed">Header</header>
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <footer class="fixed">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

That works, but remove the `position: absolute` and grows bigger than 50% (and the width changes). Why is that?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
}
.list {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.fixed {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="fixed">Header</header>
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <footer class="fixed">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is defined in the specification:

> [**10.5 Content height: the `height`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property)
>
> *`<percentage>`*
>
> Specifies a percentage height.
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block.
>
> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly
>   (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not
>   absolutely positioned, the used height is calculated as if `auto` was
>   specified.

So, here are two takeaways:

1. When your container is not absolutely positioned (i.e., it remains in-flow), the fact that there is no height defined on the parent means that `height: 50%` resolves to `height: auto` (height of the content).

   If you set, let's say, `body { height: 100vh }`, your container will take 50% height.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
}

.list {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fixed {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="fixed">Header</header>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <footer class="fixed">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

2. When your container is absolutely positioned, the `height: auto` rule doesn't apply and `height: 50%` works as intended.

   Also, in-flow block level elements take the width of their container. Once you apply absolute positioning -- removing the element from the document flow -- the "take the width of the parent" rule no longer applies, and you need to specify the width of the container, or define the offset properties (i.e., `left`, `right`, etc.).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  
  /* new */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* or this */
  /* width: 100%; */
}

.list {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fixed {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

/* new */
 * { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="fixed">Header</header>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <footer class="fixed">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

More details:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Block elements consume the full width of their parent, by default.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276)